# how to compile bibtex file using texmaker and XeLaTeX

Tags: bibtex, compiling, texmaker

I'm in doubt about the sequence `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex`.

Let's suppose I have a file called `bibliography.bib`, so it means that my sequence should be: `latex bibliography.bib`, `bibtex bibliography.bib`, `latex bibliography.bib` and `latex bibliography.bib` again?

Thanks!

p.s.: I'm using Texmaker, however I'm doing this sequence on Terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bibliography file (`.bib` extension, let us use you example `bibliography.bib`) should be included in the main latex file (let us say it is `main.tex`) using `\bibliography{bibliography}` or `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}` if you are using `biblatex`. Then the sequence is called on the main latex file. Thus the sequence is

```
latex main 
bibtex main 
latex main
latex main
```

Notice you do not have to use the extensions when you call the command (and in case, for `bibtex`, it is not `.bib`, but `.aux`).

If you use XeLaTeX, then replace `latex` with `xelatex`.