# How to connect set up bibtex when using xelatex in Texmaker?

Tags: biblatex, xetex, biber, texmaker

I have written a few reports using Overleaf but I have never used XeLaTex or Texmaker before. Now I have the problem that my citations are not showing up in the final document.

This is the basic setup, `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\chapter{One}
\input{Chapters/One.tex}
%This file includes a citation: Text text text \cite{Someone2020}.

\begin{spacing}{1}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

I only get the errors "Citation "Someone2020" on page 1 undefined" for `Chapters/One.tex` and for `main.tex` "Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file". No bibliography is printed. The file `references.bib` is in the same directory as the `main.tex` file and the `Chapters/One.tex` folder/file. It includes the citation `bla2020`.

I have the feeling this has got to do with the way Texmaker is set up. I need to use XeLaTex and changing the configuration of Texmaker to `"biber" %` for `Bib(la)tex` did not make it work.

How do I run biber on the file as suggested by the error message? Could someone explain how to solve this problem for absolute beginners?

This question sadly doesn't help me with the knowledge I have [how to compile bibtex file using texmaker and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307550/how-to-compile-bibtex-file-using-texmaker-and-xelatex).

Thank you a lot!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how to set up your editor for Biber. In theory `biber %` already looks quite good, but double check with the instructions from the link. Depending on how you editor is set up (and its heuristics if applicable), you may still have to tell your editor when to run Biber so that you indeed get the required LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX compilation cycle. How this is done depends on your editor and to some degree on your operating system, refer to the link before and to the documentation of your editor. ...

Comment: ... If you finally manage to run Biber, you should get the desired output. If not, you need to check if there were any errors during the LaTeX or Biber run. For the LaTeX run check the `.log` file, for the Biber run check the `.blg` file. More details and more hints can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864

Comment: Thank you!! That was the right hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @moewe for the right link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788. There is a tiny bit more to it when using XeLaTeX.

When set up like shown above, go to `User` -> `User Commands` -> `Edit user commands`. Then name it e.g. `Whatever` and coose the `wizard`. Add `XeLaTeX` `Bibtex` `XeLaTeX` `XeLaTeX` in this order. When compiling a document now, choose `Whatever` (i.e. the name you gave this compilation cycle) to run the commands in precisely this order.